# error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'Color')

Tags: c++

```
namespace {

    template<GenT GT, PieceT PT>
    // Move Generator for PIECE
    struct Generator
    {

    public:

        template<Color C>

        static INLINE void generate (ValMove *&m_list, const Position &pos, Bitboard targets, const CheckInfo *ci = NULL)
        {

        }

    };

    template<GenT GT>
    // Move Generator for KING
    struct Generator<GT, KING>
    {

    public:

        template<CSide SIDE, bool CHESS960>

        static INLINE void generate_castling (ValMove *&m_list, const Position &pos, Color C, const CheckInfo *ci /*= NULL*/)
        {

        }

        template<Color C>
        static INLINE void generate (ValMove *&m_list, const Position &pos, Bitboard targets, const CheckInfo *ci = NULL)
        {

        }

    };

    template<GenT GT>
    // Move Generator for PAWN
    struct Generator<GT, PAWN>
    {

    public:

        template<Delta D>
        // Generates PAWN promotion move
        static INLINE void generate_promotion (ValMove *&m_list, Bitboard pawns_on_R7, Bitboard targets, const CheckInfo *ci)
        {

        }


        template<Color C>
        static INLINE void generate (ValMove *&m_list, const Position &pos, Bitboard targets, const CheckInfo *ci = NULL)
        {

        }

    };



    template<Color C, GenT GT>
    // Generates all pseudo-legal moves of color for targets.
    INLINE ValMove* generate_moves (ValMove *&m_list, const Position &pos, Bitboard targets, const CheckInfo *ci = NULL)
    {

        // ERROR :: generate<C>
        // error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'Color'
        // for ALL CALLS TO  generate<C>

        Generator<GT, PAWN>::generate<C> (m_list, pos, targets, ci);
        Generator<GT, NIHT>::generate<C> (m_list, pos, targets, ci);
        Generator<GT, BSHP>::generate<C> (m_list, pos, targets, ci);
        Generator<GT, ROOK>::generate<C> (m_list, pos, targets, ci);
        Generator<GT, QUEN>::generate<C> (m_list, pos, targets, ci);
        if (EVASION != GT)
        {
            Generator<GT, KING>::generate<C> (m_list, pos, targets, ci);
        }

        return m_list;
    }

}
```

---

```
make.exe -f MakeFile build ARCH=x86-32 COMP=mingw
```

Why this error? I am compiling with minGW.

> `error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'Color'`

Please explain this, I have provided the full code here.

Comment: `template<GenT GT, PieceT PT>
struct Generator {}

2 specialized

template<GenT GT>
struct Generator<GT, KING> {}

template<GenT GT>
struct Generator<GT, PAWN> {}`

Comment: Can you show the code in which you are actually using `operator<`?

Answer (score 4):

Put `template` in front of `generate` in your `generate_moves` function. For example:

```
Generator<GT, PAWN>::template generate<C> (m_list, pos, targets, ci);
```

The compiler recognized the `generate` was a function type, but did not know you wanted to treat the name as a template. So, it treated the `<` after it as the less-than operator, resulting in the error that you saw.